# Support library's AsyncTaskLoad does not support being cancelled?

Tags: android, android-asynctask, android-support-library, asynctaskloader

I'm using the v13 support library and all the functions required to support cancellation such as `isLoadInBackgroundCanceled` and `cancelLoadInBackground` are completely missing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15449553/274972). The support library version doesn't support cancellation which is quite ridiculous. Only the framework version has cancellation ability.