# AsyncLoaderTask stops loading randomly (loadInBackground() stops getting called)

Tags: android, android-loader

I have a class that extends `AsyncTaskLoader` and which frequently receives updates. Now when the app initially starts everything works fine, the UI (a `SherlockListFragment` (so I am using the compatability library) that implements `LoaderManager.LoaderCallbacks<List<Item>>`) updates accordingly as updates are received. At some random point however the UI simply stops updating. So far I haven't noticed any type of pattern to ascertain when it will stop updating; it can happen when very few updates are occurring or when many updates are occurring.

Below is my custom `AsyncTaskLoader` (I simply edited class and variable names to be highly generic so as to hopefully make the code slightly simpler to understand):

```
public class CustomLoader extends AsyncTaskLoader<List<Item>> {
private static final String LOG_TAG = "CustomLoader";
private List<Item> items;

public CustomLoader(Context context) {
    super(context);
}

@Override
public List<Item> loadInBackground() {
    return ItemModel.getItemList();
}


@Override
public void deliverResult(List<Item> data) {
    if (isReset()) {
        if (data != null) {
            Log.w(LOG_TAG, "Warning! An async query came in while the Loader was reset!");
            releaseResources(data);
            return;
        }
    }

    // Hold a reference to the old data so it doesn't get garbage collected.
    // We must protect it until the new data has been delivered.
    List<Item> oldItems = items;
    items = data;

    if (isStarted()) {
        Log.i(LOG_TAG, "Delivering results to the LoaderManager.");
        // If the Loader is in a started state, have the superclass deliver the
        // results to the client.
        super.deliverResult(data);
    }

    // Invalidate the old data as we don't need it any more.
    if (oldItems != null && oldItems != data) {
        Log.i(LOG_TAG, "Releasing any old data associated with this Loader.");
        releaseResources(oldItems);
    }
}

@Override
protected void onStartLoading() {
    Log.i(LOG_TAG, "onStartLoading() called!");

    if (items != null) {
        // Deliver any previously loaded data immediately.
        Log.i(LOG_TAG, "Delivering previously loaded data to the client");
        deliverResult(items);
    }

            //Initialises the loader within the model 
    ItemModel.registerLoader(this);

    if (takeContentChanged()) {
        forceLoad();
    }
    else if (items == null) {
        // If the current data is null... then we should make it non-null! :)
        forceLoad();
    }
}

@Override
protected void onStopLoading() {
    Log.i(LOG_TAG, "onStopLoading() called!");

    // The Loader has been put in a stopped state, so we should attempt to
    // cancel the current load (if there is one).
    cancelLoad();
}

@Override
protected void onReset() {
    Log.i(LOG_TAG, "onReset() called!");
    super.onReset();

    // Ensure the loader is stopped.
    onStopLoading();
    // At this point we can release the resources associated.
    if (items != null) {
        releaseResources(items);
        items = null;
    }
    // The Loader is being reset, so we should stop monitoring for changes.
            // We do this by making the loader instance null
    ItemModel.deregisterLoader();
}


@Override
public void onCanceled(List<Item> data) {
    Log.i(LOG_TAG, "onCanceled() called!");

    /**
     * So... we were having problems with the loader sometimes simply not refreshing. It was found
     * that when receiving two updates in quick succession, the loader would call onCanceled() after 
     * the second update (in order to try to stop the previous load). Whenever onCanceled() was called,
     * the loader would stop refreshing. 
     * 
     * And the reason for this?? The support library version of Loader does not support onCanceled() !!!
     * Thanks to this answer on stack overflow for bringing up the issue - http://stackoverflow.com/a/15449553
     * By examining the API for the support library and the API 11 versions of Loader, it is clear that
     * we shouldn't be receiving onCanceled() calls here, but we still do!
     * 
     * Also important to note is that even on Android 3.0 and up, the framework will still use the 
     * support library methods for Loader.
     * 
     * So we simply swallow this onCanceled() call and don't call the super method. This seems to fix 
     * the issue - it may also work if we simply remove onCanceled() completely, but not 100% sure. 
     */

        // Attempt to cancel the current asynchronous load.
    //super.onCanceled(data);

    // The load has been canceled, so we should release the associated resources
            //Uncommenting this line of code does not resolve my issue
    //releaseResources(data);
}

@Override
public void forceLoad() {
    Log.i(LOG_TAG, "forceLoad() called!");
    super.forceLoad();
}

private void releaseResources(List<Item> data) {
    // All resources associated with the Loader should be released here.
    if (data != null) {
        data.clear();
        data = null;
    }
}
}
```

Now, while the UI is still updating properly the Logs show the following sequence of events:

```
03-03 17:23:33.859: I/CustomLoader(20663): forceLoad() called!
03-03 17:23:33.859: I/CustomLoader(20663): Load in background called...
03-03 17:23:33.864: I/CustomLoader(20663): Delivering results to the LoaderManager.
03-03 17:23:33.864: D/CustomFragment(20663): onLoadFinished() for loader_id 0
03-03 17:23:33.869: I/CustomLoader(20663): Releasing any old data associated with this Loader.
```

whenever the data is updated.

At the point that the UI stops updating it seems as though `forceLoad()` keeps on getting called every time the data changes it doesn't seem to actually accomplish anything (i.e. `loadInBackground()` doesn't get called). I have done a lot of research, looking at other implementations of `AsyncTaskLoader` and the overall logic of my implementation is similar to everything I've found so I'm at a bit of a loss here.